# What is the appropriate way to draw attention to my edited on-hold question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen, on-hold

My question ([How to increment upvote total in my view after successful Ajax request to upvote action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743387/how-to-increment-upvote-total-in-my-view-after-successful-ajax-request-to-upvote)) was put on hold for being too broad, and upon further reflection I agreed. It has since been edited, and it is much clearer now. However, nothing has changed since then, which was three days ago, and nobody has responded to my comments asking if there is anything I could further change to make it more acceptable. I flagged it to draw moderator attention as the on-hold question guide recommended, but that didn't appear to draw any. I desperately need an answer and want to put a bounty on it as soon as possible. What is an acceptable way to get people to view my on-hold question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By editing the question it will have been added to the Reopen Review queue where people with close vote privileges will be able to see at and decide if it's worth reopening.

You could try posting a link in an appropriate chat room to see if you can attract the attention of such users.

At the time of writing it has 4 reopen votes so it's well on the way to being reopened, so I don't think you have much to worry about here. When you get to 250 rep you'll be able to see the close and reopen vote count on your own questions, so you wouldn't be so in the dark.

If you don't think that's enough they you can try what you've done here by posting a question on Meta - but be warned you might not get what you expect, especially if people think you haven't done enough.

What you shouldn't do is flag it for moderator attention. We're not here to reopen questions so I've declined your flag - sorry.